# Removing Line between the content Pane and the TitleBar

Tags: dojo, dijit.layout

I have a dijit.dialog which I have made transparent and changed the background color of TitleBar but I can see a line between the titleBar and the content.
I want to remove that line.

Please guide.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you could add some CSS to remove that border, for example:

```
 .dijitDialogPaneContent {border-top:0 !important;}
```